# Can I put two if statements next to each other in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I'm trying to get my JavaScript to apply a class if specific values from my array show up. It moves through the values on button click. 3 of the 4 values aren't centered in the div so I'm trying to apply a class `bottomclass` to them.

I suspect that the issue is that I'm using two if statements without closing off one of them with an else ending. I have two other circles like the one above, they share the same class in the div, could this be effecting this? Please let me know if something else is the issue.

I've tried using className & classList, using replace, add, & remove. The entire array is changed, or the class isn't applied--in the code below the class isn't applied. I've tried just changing the `top` value, but nothing happens. I've tried just changing the colors (to dumb it down for myself) and nothing is happening. I've tried changing the amount of equal signs in the second if statement, and the class works correctly when using one equal sign but the rest of the values are overwritten with "undefined".

```js
var skills1 = ["Excel", "Word", "Power Bi", "Power Point"];
var i = 0;

function MultiTaskSwitch1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("multitask1");
  x.innerHTML = skills1[i++];
  if (i == skills1.length) {
    i = 0;
  }
  if (i == skills1[1]) {
    x.className = "bottomskill"
  } else {
    x.className = "skillsset"
  };
}
```

```css
.skillsset {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
}

.circle {
  width: 108px;
  height: 93px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: aqua;
}

.bottomskill {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: pink;
  text-align: center;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!--The DIV that displays, it's in a circle-->
<div class="circle skills">
  <p class="skillsset" onclick="MultiTaskSwitch1()" id="multitask1">Click<br> Me</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `i == skills[1]` is probably not doing what you think/want

Comment: `if specific values from my array show up` when it shows up where?

Comment: My apologies for not being clear. The values are located within a circle/div. What should I replace "i == skills1[1]" with?

Comment: Why are you comparing `i` (an index) with `skills1[1]` (a value)?

Comment: I thought that i represented a variable and skills[1] was referencing the value by index number? To keep things easy to read and reference, I thought using the array index would be helpful. It sounds like I mixed that up.

Answer (score 3):

The main issue in your code is in the condition of the subsequent if statement:

```
if (i == skills[1]) { // This comparison is not correct
  x.className = "bottomskill"
} else {
  x.className = "skillsset"
}
```

In your case, you want to apply the "bottomskill" class if skills1[i] equals a specific value, so you should modify the condition to compare skills1[i] with the desired value. For example:

```
if (skills1[i] === "Power Point") { // Replace "Power Point" with the desired value
  x.className = "bottomskill";
} else {
  x.className = "skillsset";
}
```

This way, the "bottomskill" class will be applied when the current value in your skills1 array matches "Power Point." Make sure to do the same for other values in your array if you want to apply different classes for each value.

Additionally, note that you can simplify the code by using classList to add and remove classes without completely overwriting the className:

```
if (skills1[i] === "Power Point") {
  x.classList.remove("skillsset");
  x.classList.add("bottomskill");
} else {
  x.classList.remove("bottomskill");
  x.classList.add("skillsset");
}
```

This way, you can easily manage CSS classes by adding or removing them based on the desired condition. I hope all this helps you

Comment: Thank you! I tried what you suggested with slight tweaking. I did this: if(skills1[i] == skills1[1]) and it works! Do I have to make a separate IF statement for the rest of the values becuase I can't get the || (OR operator) to work within the brackets.